# Network auto-discovery using SNMP and .NET

Tags: .net, networking, snmp

Are there any libraries, (third party is fine) that can help do network auto-discovery using SNMP and .NET?

If not, have you ever rolled your own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've recently come across [Sharp SNMP Suite](http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com) which I think does what you're asking for. I say "think" as I've not actually used it myself yet! I've just started looking into SNMP for the first time for a forthcoming project.

Answer (score 8):

as the author of #SNMP, I can confirm that it supports basic auto discovery feature. Just simply call Manager.Discover. There is also a discussion thread for your reference.

http://www.codeplex.com/sharpsnmplib/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=32902

Regards,

-Lex

Answer (score 1):

- HP OpenView does network discovery using SNMP.  It might be worth looking into how they do it
- Another suggestion is to work out your gateway and get the routers it is connected to via SNMP

Answer (score 0):

It's a little old topic but may still be useful for someones. I use to work with [SNMP](http://www.oidview.com/mibbrowser.html) from Oidview, they have a trial as well.

Comment: But can it be used from a .NET application?